# Use of =lookup() - using multiple columns e.g. =LOOKUP(a1,$E$1:$F$24,$G$1:$G$24)

Tags: excel

I just found out how to lookup a date within a range of dates (source: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/621562-vlookup-if-date-between-2-dates-table.html)

Although, I cannot seem to find any documentation on how =lookup() searches both columns. Can someone please explain how it works?

Please see below for the formula, and example data.

Formula:

```
=LOOKUP(b1,$a$5:$b$7,$c$5:$c$7)
```

Example:

```
Lookup  9/10/2017
Result  Week 2

Week Start  Week End    Week Number
27/09/2017  3/10/2017   Week 1
4/10/2017   10/10/2017  Week 2
11/10/2017  17/10/2017  Week 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after 1 more google search - I've found the answer (and in the place I really should have looked first):

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LOOKUP-function-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb

The above says: =lookup() can use either a vector syntax or an array syntax.

If you input an array to search - it uses the largest value in the array that is less than or equal to lookup_value. Based on testing - it matches the row based on this (and will search both columns to find a value). E.g. If the first column of data is deleted, and you lookup a date that preceeds 03/10/2017, it will return "#N/A", if the first column is not deleted, that search will return "Week 1".

Not sure if I should delete this question - seeing as this is well documented in the microsoft office docs - if someone could please let me know if that's best thing to do or not that'd be much appreciated.

Comment: LOOKUP doesn't search in two columns - in the array form it only looks in the first column (or row) of the array.In the vector form (which you are using) you should be using a vector (a single row or column), so your version is equivalent to =LOOKUP(b1,$a$5:$a$7,$c$5:$c$7) b1 is matched with the largest value in A5:A7 that <= B1 and A5:A7 must be sorted ascending